# HTTP status code 401 even though I’m sending credentials in the request

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, cors, httprequest

Recently i have introduced JWT authentication to my Springboot and Angualr2 based App.
In There i tried to do a POST request by passing the JWT token as below in my Angualr code

```js
save(jobId: number, taskId: number, note: Note) {

   return this.http.post(environment.APIENDPOINT + '/jobs/' + jobId + '/tasks/' + taskId + '/notes', note, this.setHeaders()).map((response: Response) => response.json());

}
```

```js
private setHeaders() {
        // create authorization header with jwt token
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log("Current token---"+ currentUser.token);
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('authorization','Bearer '+ currentUser.token);
            
   let r = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
   return r;

        }
    }
```

However in the server side it returns status code 401. The issue is in the Springboot side it checks the authorization header as below and it returns null

```
String authToken = request.getHeader("authorization ");
```

Then i had a look at the request header and it has the authorization header under Access-Control-Request-Headers as below. But it is not visible to the server side.

[image]

Then i read further and found that this could be an issue with CORS configuration. So i have modified my CORS configuration filter to have addExposedHeader as below

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addExposedHeader("authorization");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");

    //config.addExposedHeader("Content-Type");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Still the server complains that it can not find the Authorization header. Did i miss any thing here? Appreciate your help

Solution

After reading the sideshowbarker's comment below, i was able to understand the basics behind the issue.
In My Project I have a JWT token filter and inside that it always checks the Authorization header. Then i have modified it as below and now it works as expected

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }else{
        String authToken = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
        jWTTokenAuthenticationService.parseClaimsFromToken(authToken);
        --
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}Catch(AuthenticationException authEx){
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    if (entryPoint != null) {
        entryPoint.commence(request, response, authEx);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have answered the same issue
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735921/ajax-cors-request-with-http-401-in-preflight/61301832#61301832)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to configure the server to not require authorization for `OPTIONS` requests (that is, the server the request is being sent to — not the one serving your frontend code).

That’s because what’s happening is this:

1. Your code tells your browser it wants to send a request with the `Authorization` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with the `Authorization` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` to ensure the server allows requests with the `Authorization` header.
3. Your browser sends the `OPTIONS` request **without the `Authorization` header**, because the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` check is to see if it’s OK to include that header.
4. Your server sees the `OPTIONS` request but rejects it with a 401 since it lacks the header.
5. Your browser expects a 200 or 204 response for the CORS preflight but instead gets that 401. So your browser stops right there and never tries the `POST` request from your code.

---

Further details:

The `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` request headers show in the question indicate the browser’s doing a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

And the presence of the `Authorization` and `Content-Type: application/json` request headers in your request are what trigger your browser do that CORS preflight — by sending an `OPTIONS` request to the server before trying the `POST` request in your code. And because that `OPTIONS` preflight fails, the browser stops right there and never attempts the `POST`.

So you must figure out what part of the server-side code on the server the request is being sent to causes it to require authorization for `OPTIONS` requests, and change that so it instead responds to `OPTIONS`  with a 200 or 204 success response without requiring authorization.

---

For specific help on `OPTIONS`-enabling a Spring server in particular, see the following answers:

- [Disable Spring Security for OPTIONS Http Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696592/disable-spring-security-for-options-http-method/26848692#26848692)
- [Spring CorsFilter does not seem to work still receiving a 401 on preflight requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601712/spring-corsfilter-does-not-seem-to-work-still-receiving-a-401-on-preflight-reque/38618974#38618974)
- [Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 - Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370022/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-401-spring/40374505#40374505)
- [AngularJS & Spring Security with ROLE_ANONYMOUS still returns 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926503/angularjs-spring-security-with-role-anonymous-still-returns-401/29943074#29943074)

Comment: i have a JWT token filter and inside that it always checks the Authorization header. I had to modify that logic to ignore the OPTION requests for token filtering and set the status 200

Comment: how about CORS white lists, which are configured by tenant? how could you possibly generate an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, without knowing which tenant, which configuration to use, this looks like an oversight to me....