# Make a http request with ajax for basic authorization and cors

Tags: javascript, apache, authentication, cors, jqxhr

The config for my httpd server `111.111.111.111` (supposed).
Config for cors and basic auth in  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With"
</Directory>
```

Make some more configs for basic authorization on my server `111.111.111.111`.

```
cd /var/www/html && vim .htaccess
AuthName "login"  
AuthType Basic  
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/passwd  
require user username
```

Create password for username.

```
htpasswd -c /var/www/html/passwd username
```

Reboot httpd with :

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

The `/var/www/html/remote.html` on the server `111.111.111.111` .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" />
</head>
<body>
<p>it is a test </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Test it with username and passwd when to open `111.111.111.111\remote.html?username=xxxx&password=xxxx` in browser.

```
it is a test
```

Get the response header with curl.

```
curl -u xxxx:xxxx -I  http://111.111.111.111/remote.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 00:59:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,X-PINGOTHER,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Sep 2018 15:01:05 GMT
ETag: "f5-575210b30e3cb"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Add a parameter  `OPTIONS` in header .

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i http://111.111.111.111/remote.html

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 06:42:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,X-PINGOTHER,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="please login"
Content-Length: 381
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Add `OPTIONS` and basic authorization in header.

```
curl -X OPTIONS -u xxxx:xxxxx  -i http://111.111.111.111/remote.html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 06:42:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,X-PINGOTHER,DNT,User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,accept,origin,X-Requested-With
Allow: POST,OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,TRACE
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Ok, everything is good status.
Let's try ajax's basic authorization.

The `/var/www/html/test.html` on my local apache.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    function Ajax( ) {
        var url = 'http://111.111.111.111/remote.html';
        $.ajax(url, {
            type:"get",
            dataType: 'html',
            withCredentials: true,
            username: "xxxx",
            password: "xxxx",
            success:function(response){
                mytext = $("#remote");
                mytext.append(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("error");
            }    
        });
    };
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="show content" onclick="Ajax();">
    <p id="remote">the content on remote webpage</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To click `show content` button when to input `127.0.0.1/test.html`,i got the error:

```
GET http://111.111.111.111/remote.html 401 (Unauthorized)
```

[image]

I have given a detailed description based on httpd setting (centos7) and ajax and others related to the issue, please download my code and save it in your vps and local htdocs directory, replace ip with your real ip, reproduce the process.
I  beg you not to make any comments until you reproduce the process.
you may find what happened, maybe it is same as mine here.

Two important elements in the issue.
1.httpd setting  in the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.
2.ajax code
Which one is wrong?
How to fix it?

I have some clue to solve the issue, thanks to @sideshowbarker.

[reason](http://%20%20[2]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405983/http-status-code-401-even-though-i-m-sending-an-authorization-request-header/45406085#45406085)

The problem turns into another one:
How to configure the apache to not require authorization for OPTIONS requests?
I have tried as  `Disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request)` say.

[Disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request)e](http://%20%20[2]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405983/http-status-code-401-even-though-i-m-sending-an-authorization-request-header/45406085#45406085)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

`systemctl restart httpd`,failed.

Comment: What happens when you try `curl -X OPTIONS -i  http://111.111.111.111/remote.html`?

Comment: Please view my revised post,and do as i say in your vps.

Comment: The problem with adding the credentials to the OPTIONS request is, browsers don’t add them when they do CORS preflights. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-credentials%E2%91%A5 (*“a CORS-preflight request never includes credentials”*). Instead for the preflight, browsers send an OPTIONS request without any Authorization header. That means the server receiving the request must be configured to accept OPTIONS requests without requiring authentication, & must response to those unauthenticated OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK. Otherwise the preflight fails. That’s the problem you’ve run into

Comment: See also the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405983/http-status-code-401-even-though-i-m-sending-an-authorization-request-header/45406085#45406085

Comment: I guess it's not really a direct answer to your question but you really shouldn't send a plaintext password over HTTP as a GET request.

Comment: try disabling web security of the browser. in Chrome:  `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir` Sometimes browsers will not allow accessing CORS

Answer (score 3):

If you `console.log` the error you will see a message saying:

> Failed to load http://111.111.111.111/remote.html: The value of the **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** header in the response **must not be the wildcard '*' when** the request's **credentials mode is 'include'**. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1/' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the `XMLHttpRequest` is controlled by the `withCredentials` attribute.

This is to **protect against CSRF attacks**.

E.g. If wildcard could be used in this case: Malicious-`SiteA` could **access** privileged resources **without authorization** on target-`SiteB` through **browser-initiated ajax reqests**, just because victim at some point provided crendentials for `SiteB`, while he was on trusted-`SiteC`.

So the **solution** is to just change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from "*" to "http://127.0.0.1", (`SiteC` address in the example above)

---

Now in order for `curl -X OPTIONS -i http://111.111.111.111/remote.html` to work while keeping active authentication for other methods, you need to  **add the following to `.htaccess`, or to `httpd.conf`**:

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
   AuthName "login"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile /var/www/cors-auth.passwd
   Require user username
 </LimitExcept>
```

**EDIT:**

`LimitExcept OPTIONS` is **required if you need to prefill** the username/password (as in your case), **instead of expecting** the browser to **prompt a dialog**. But to make it work on all browsers (chrome/ff/edge), 
**I had to replace this:**

```
        withCredentials: true,
        username: "xxxx",
        password: "xxxx",
```

with this:

```
      beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa("xxxx:xxxx")); 
       },
```

Answer (score 1):

try putting localhost instead of 'http://111.111.111.111/remote.html'

'http://localhost/remote.html .It should work .It may be your public ip address issue where port 80 is not open.

Comment: But then there is no need to use CORS headers. The question is about using authorization+cors, which means main page and ajax part should belong to a differrent domain.

Comment: Cors has to be fixed at the requesting url . If you are doing ajax call to remote server/asd.php  then you have to  open course at remote server.In his case he is just replicating remote server and local server as 111.111.111.111 so there is no cors as its from  111.111.111.111 to 111.111.111.111.