# Angular 6, HtttpClient, with BackEnd Spring Boot! My Header don't reach to the backend

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http-headers

I'm trying to do a `get` request with `headers` because in my backEnd there is a check for the token which I generate in the login. But for some reason, I can't obtain the Authorization header and I print all the headers in the console and I don't see my header

here is the code of my service in Angular 6

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Usuario } from '../clases/usuario';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
getAllUsers(token: string) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };
  httpOptions.headers = httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', token);
  return this.http.request('GET', this.usuarioUrl, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map((resp: Usuario[]) => {
        this.usuarios = resp;
        return this.usuarios;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

here is my filter in my backEnd

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().endsWith("/auth/login") ||
        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().endsWith("/auth/signup"))) {

      HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
      String authHeader = httpRequest.getHeader(AuthUtils.AUTH_HEADER_KEY);
      Enumeration < String > test = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
      while (test.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = test.nextElement();
        logger.info("Header " + headerName);
        logger.info("getHeader " + httpRequest.getHeader(headerName));
      }
      logger.info("AuthHeader " + authHeader);
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || authHeader.split(" ").length != 1) {
        logger.error("No token");
        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, AUTH_ERROR_MSG);
      } else {
        JWTClaimsSet claimSet = null;
        try {
          claimSet = (JWTClaimsSet) AuthUtils.decodeToken(authHeader);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, JWT_ERROR_MSG);
          return;
        } catch (JOSEException e) {
          httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, JWT_INVALID_MSG);
          return;
        }
        // ensure that the token is not expired
        if (new DateTime(claimSet.getExpirationTime()).isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
          httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, EXPIRE_ERROR_MSG);
        } else {
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
      }
    } else {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

and my console is this

```
2018-09-16 19:57:00.877  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header host
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader localhost:8091
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header connection
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader keep-alive
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header access-control-request-method
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader POST
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header origin
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader http://localhost:4200
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header user-agent
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header access-control-request-headers
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader authorization,content-type
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header accept
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader */*
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header accept-encoding
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader gzip, deflate, br
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : Header accept-language
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : getHeader es-ES,es;q=0.9
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878  INFO 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : AuthHeader null
2018-09-16 19:57:00.878 ERROR 8880 --- [nio-8091-exec-7] py.edu.una.rest.filters.AuthFilter       : No token
```

how can obtain the Authorization header in my backend to check? please Help! why doesn't it reach my backEnd?

Comment: Can you please show value of AuthUtils.AUTH_HEADER_KEY and did you debug at client side token is passed.

Comment: public static final String AUTH_HEADER_KEY = "Authorization";

Comment: yes I print console.log(token) and the token is there

Comment: Your filter code is fine and working as i just checked with rest client, can you change AUTH_HEADER_KEY  to 'authorization"

Comment: your logs are also not showing Authorization so seems some issue with client side not sending Authorization in header as for me it shows Header authorization logs
2018-09-17 08:24:11.497  INFO 14664 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.k.d.config.JWTAuthorizationFilter      : getHeader sjdkdjksdjjfldfkldfkdlfkdlkfldkfdk

Comment: you use my code of the client side for your test? Thank you for the response

Comment: Can you share your  code on github and provide me url

Comment: client: https://github.com/slashispy/fronEndProy.git

Comment: backEnd: https://github.com/slashispy/proyecto.git

Comment: Sure will check and update

Comment: let header = new HttpHeaders();
    header = header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header = header.append('Authorization', token);

const httpOptions ={ headers:header};

can you try changing the way the headers are created

Comment: @AndrésPlanás please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code in filter to allow OPTIONS methods requests, the changes I made are mainly here:

```
if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```

To understand why OPTIONS are required to please read answer from this thread: [OPTIONS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405983/http-status-code-401-even-though-i-m-sending-an-authorization-request-header) and [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests), this will solve your problem for now.

Your filter method code in `AuthFilter`

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            if (!(((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().endsWith("/auth/login")
                    || ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().endsWith("/auth/signup"))){

                String authHeader = httpRequest.getHeader(AuthUtils.AUTH_HEADER_KEY);
                Enumeration<String> prueba = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
                while ( prueba.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String headerName = prueba.nextElement();
                    logger.info("Header "+ headerName);
                    logger.info("getHeader "+httpRequest.getHeader(headerName));
                }
                logger.info("AuthHeader "+ authHeader);
                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || authHeader.split(" ").length != 1) {
                    logger.error("No tiene token");
                    httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, AUTH_ERROR_MSG);
                } else {
                    JWTClaimsSet claimSet = null;
                    try {
                        claimSet = (JWTClaimsSet) AuthUtils.decodeToken(authHeader);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, JWT_ERROR_MSG);
                        return;
                    } catch (JOSEException e) {
                        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, JWT_INVALID_MSG);
                        return;
                    }
                    // ensure that the token is not expired
                    if (new DateTime(claimSet.getExpirationTime()).isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
                        httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, EXPIRE_ERROR_MSG);
                    } else {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Recommended:**

I will recommend to use Spring security to manage your Auth Filter and OPTIONS requests from overriding http like below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
     http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()//allow CORS option calls
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .//add filter here

}
```

Comment: Thanks @kj007 this solve the problem you save my life!