# Custom headers are stripped from my request

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, cors, axios, fetch

I'm trying to add a Authorization header to my get request from my react app to Spring boot back-end. I've tried both fetch and axios:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/tender', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer' + token,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        });

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer' + token;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/tender').then((res) => console.log(res));
```

My raw header viewed from devtools:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept-Language: nb-NO,nb;q=0.9,no-NO;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn-NO;q=0.5,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,authorization
Referer: http://localhost:3000/import
Origin: http://localhost:3000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
```

Somehow my custom headers are removed before calling the api and I get the following error: `Missing security token, please log in` If I edit and resend the same reuqest adding Authorization to my header, the api reponds with 200

Edit:

Ignoring token validation for http Options method gives a 200 response. But my initial request never runs. I would expect my get-request to run as soon as the option method returns OK

Comment: The request headers shown in the question are for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request made by the browser automatically on its own, before attempting the GET request from your code. What the question shows is expected behavior. Browsers intentionally by design don’t include any headers in that preflight OPTIONS request other than the headers the browser sets on its own. As a consequence, that means the server the request is sent to must allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests (without expecting an Authorization header or any other credentials). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45406085/441757

Comment: By the way, remove `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` from the headers object in your frontend code. That header is a response header only. Trying to set it as a request header will not help you.

Comment: Shouldn't my initial get request run as soon as the options request returns ok?

Comment: If the options request actually does return ok —with the right response headers  — then yeah, the browser will your run get request. So if the browser isn’t running your get request, then that means the browser has determined the preflight didn’t succeed. That could be because the status code for the options response was an error code rather than a 200 OK success response, or it could be because the options response doesn’t have the headers the browser expects. So you look at the error messages the browser has logged in devtools console. And use the Network page to get the response status code

Comment: I'm already getting a  200 OK success response after I removed the token validation for http options method. My get request still doesn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preflight Options request wasn't handled properly in my Spring boot back-end .Turns out I was missing a cors configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

This configuration solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem but isn't a space missing after 'Bearer' ?

```
'Bearer'+token => 'Bearer '+token ?
```

Comment: There is no Authorization value in my request header. If the the token was included, my back-end would have returned a invalid not missing token error message