# CORS don't work after JWT authentication added

Tags: vue.js, cors, fastify

I have a Vue frontend, an Auth0 and Fastify backend. CORS is configured as follows:

```js
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD',
  allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
})
```

Frontend headers configuration:

```js
this.$auth.getTokenSilently().then(token => {
  this.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` // send the access token through the 'Authorization' header
  };
```

The problem is common:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/dir' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've read a lot about CORS, know this is a browser side problem (Insomnia sends requests perfectly). Actually, I do not have clear understanding of what else I should allow and how. Basically I need only standart GET, PUT, POST, DELETE requests allowed. Could you please point out the exact configuration problems in my code?

[image]

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000, have you tried to give access for origin you have problem with ?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * -  this will give access to any request from any origin

Comment: I tried *, it was actually before. Don't work either. But I've read thet there must be an explicit origin config. Origin which tries to access API's endpoint is at 8080, not at 3000.

Comment: origin: (origin, cb) => {
  if(/localhost/.test(origin)){
    //  Request from localhost will pass
    cb(null, true)
    return
  }
  // Generate an error on other origins, disabling access
  cb(new Error("Not allowed"))
}

have you tried code from doc ?

Comment: The same result

Comment: It seems that preflight doesn't have a token, this causes 401. But I don't understand how to cope with it cause preflight request is sent by a browser.

Comment: Yeah, the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/dir` server needs to be configured to not require authentication for OPTIONS requests. That’s the only change this will fix this. The server much respond to unauthenticated OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK and the necessary CORS headers. For a more-detailed explanation, see the the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45406085/441757

Comment: 401 is cured, but still have CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: It's seems that axios POST request doesn't include Authorization header in request. But: `axios
            .post(`${c.api.path}/dir`, {path: this.cRoot}, this.headers)` and console.log shows that this.headers contains a correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First 401 was caused by OPTIONS request without autentication token. Actually it should be seamlessly processed by a *fastify-cors*. But due to an incorrect order of initialisation of on-request hooks (first - mine to autenticate, using *fastify-auth0-verify*, second - implicit hook from *fastify-cors*), it never invoked. So you need a precise order of hooks explicit and implicit initialization: **first - cors**, then **second - authentication**.
2. The second problem, 401 on the following POST, happened because of incorrect usage of an *axios* request params on the frontend Vue side. Headers like `{ Authorization: 'Bearer SomeVeryLongSecretXYZ'}`were passed as, for instance, `...post(url, data, this.headers)`, but there must be **`{headers : this.headers}`**.
3. Final configuration for CORS:

```js
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), {
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
})
```